Coins in Boxes New Zealand Committee Workshop Question
Please help me with this question:
In each of six boxes $B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5, B_6$ there is initially one coin. There are two
allowed moves:
$(a)$ Remove one coin from box $B_j$ with $1 ≤ j ≤ 5$ and add two coins to $B_{{j+1}}$.
$(b)$ Remove one coin from box $B_k$ with $1 ≤ k ≤ 4$ and swap the contents of boxes $B_{k+1}$
and $B_{k+2}$.
Is it possible to obtain a situation in which box $B_6$ contains more than $2^{{2^{{2^{{2024}}}}}}$
coins?
This is a fun workshop question and not a real exam question (search it up if you like).
I began with ${{B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5, B_6}}$ as $1,1,1,1,1,1$ as stated above.
Then I began to list out all possibilities.
If you follow $(a)$ procedure, you can get $0,3,1,1,1,1$ or $1,0,3,1,1,1$ or $1,1,0,3,1,1$ or $1,1,1,0,3,1$ or $1,1,1,1,0,3$.
If you follow $(b)$ procedure, you can get $0,1,1,1,1,1$ and if you continue, you realize that you are just wasting a box and leaving it with $0$ coins, making procedure $b$ not a feasible one.
As you can see, once you begin to list cases to find a pattern, it begins to become quite tedious and error prone. If anyone could give me a solution to this question (Yes/No) I would appreciate it very much.

In part a, do you mean add two coins to $B_{j+1}$? As opposed to $B_j+1$?

Yes, sorry. I will edit that.

A better start is to try with fewer boxes.  With $1$ you can't do anything useful.  With $2$ you can get $3$ (is that $2^2-1?$).  With $3$ you can go to $0,3,1$ and then to $0,0,7$ or to $1,0,3$, then $0,3,0$ and $0,0,6$ or to $1,0,3$ then $0,2,3$ and $0,0,7$.  We aren't seeing a hint of the explosion yet.  What about $4$ boxes?

@RossMillikan Thank you for your hint, it is starting to work, however I still am unable to finish it. If you could please provide a solution, that would be really helpful.

By the way, this is from the 2010 IMO: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2010_IMO_Problems/Problem_5

Yes. The key is to discover a critical move pattern: suppose you have three consecutive boxes with $x, y, 0$ coins, respectively. Playing move (a) $y$ times transforms this into $x, 0, 2y$. Then play move (b) to make this $x - 1, 2y, 0$. Repeat these steps $x$ times to get $0, 2^xy, 0$. If $y=0$, you can instead start with move (a) to get $x - 1, 2, 0$, and then proceed as before; you’ll end up with $0, 2^x, 0$. For convenience, I’ll call this overall transformation “move (c).” You can repeat move (c) as long as you have room on the right, which leads to extremely large numbers involving exponent towers of $2$'s.
Here’s one solution that exceeds $2^{2^{2^{2024}}}$. I’ll notate moves as “letternumber,” where the letter is the type of move (a, b, or c) and the number is the position ($j$ or $k$ in your notation, or the position of $x$ in move c).
Start:
$1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1$
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5:
$0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3$
a5x2:
$0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 7$
b4, a5x7, b4:
$0, 2, 2, 0, 14, 0$
b3:
$0, 2, 1, 14, 0, 0$
c4:
$0, 2, 1, 0, 2^{14}, 0$
b3:
$0, 2, 0, 2^{14}, 0, 0$
c4:
$0, 2, 0, 0, 2^{2^{14}}, 0$
a2, b3:
$0, 1, 1, 2^{2^{14}}, 0, 0$
c4:
$0, 1, 1, 0, 2^{2^{2^{14}}}, 0$
b3, b2:
$0, 0, 2^{2^{2^{14}}}, 0, 0, 0$
c3, c4:
$0, 0, 0, 0, 2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{14}}}}}, 0$
a5x$2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{14}}}}}$:
$0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2^{1+ 2^{2^{2^{2^{14}}}}}$
This wins by a lot. You can make it even more ridiculous by recursing move (c) when you have a pattern of the form $x, 0, 0, 0$.

Thank you for your answer. I would appreciate it if you could clarify what you mean by a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 which changes $1,1,1,1,1,1$ into $0,2,2,2,2,3$. Is it done with every consecutive group of 3 or am I misunderstanding it. Thank you very much.

Do move (a) for $j = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, in that order (although order doesn't matter in this case). This removes 1 from boxes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and adds 2 to boxes 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, so the new totals are 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3.

Thank you for your reply, +1
